# Find code in list of codes

Tags: sql

I have created a table that has a column `code` with an 8-digit code (i.e. `"8MKL98LO"`) and another one, `list_of_codes`, with a string of 8-digit codes (i.e. `"8MKL98LO", "89FLOP7P"`). I need to do a select statement that would tell me whether the first code is included in the other column that has multiple ones.

If I had always the same codes in the second column I could just do something like:

```
IF(code in ("8MKL98LO", "89FLOP7P"), 1, 0)
```

but it doesn't work if I try something like:

```
IF(code in list of codes, 1, 0)
```

Any suggestions? I feel it should be pretty easy but I can't find a way that works.

Thanks!

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Have you tried `LIKE`: `WHERE list_of_codes LIKE %code%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the database, which would affect actual syntax, I would just use the LIKE operator i.e.:

```
select * from TABLE where LIST_OF_CODES like concat('%', CODE, '%');
```

or:

```
select case when LIST_OF_CODES like concat('%', CODE, '%') then 1 else 0 end from TABLE;
```

The first only shows rows that have code in list of codes and the second shows all rows, but only gives a specific flag to ones that match, in this case a 1.

Comment: Yes. Like is a good way. You might be better off with making another table for list_of_codes... just a suggestion though.

Comment: Just a note, concat is a product specific. (ANSI SQL has ||.)

Answer (score 0):

The first suggestion is to not store lists of things as strings.  If you want a list, use a table -- that is how relational databases are designed to work.  Such a table would have one row per code and per entities, so what is on one row would have multiple rows.

If for some reason you are stuck with the structure you have described, then the basic solution is:

```
where ',' || list_of_codes || ',' like '%,' || code || ',%'
```

Notice the use of delimiters on both sides.  This is a preventive measure.  Because all your codes are 8-characters and (presumably) do not contain commas, this is not strictly necessary, so:

```
where list_of_codes like '%' || code || '%'
```

would also work in this case.  It is just dangerous if someday 7-character or 9-character codes were introduced.

Also note that `||` is used as string concatenation.  This varied by database, so it might be `+` or the `concat()` function or even `&`.

Some databases have built-in functions to do this.  For instance, in MySQL you can write:

```
where find_in_set(code, list_of_codes) > 0
```

But, the fundamental advice still stands:  create a junction table so you are not storing lists of things in a string.